# Can I connect a bidet spray to the shut off valve of the faucet?

Tags: toilet, faucet, shutoff

In my new home the toilet tank is in the wall. There is no access to the toilet shut off valve to install a bidet spray.
The faucet has a reasonable distance from the toilet. I was wondering if is it ok to install the bidet spray on the shut off valve of the faucet? Is there anything that I have to mind?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's going to be interesting to use in the winter with the cold water being fed to the toilet...

Comment: I'd hope there is an access panel _somewhere_ nearby. Plumbing fixtures don't last forever, valves, etc. need to be replaced. Maybe something on the wall behind the fixture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is basically the same water, and probably the toilet tees off of it.

Just need a longer pipe/hose, than from the toilet.